# How to to prevent data.frame function from sorting my data

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to prevent data.frame function from sorting out my data, I used match() to prevent sorting in my initial code, but when I moved to ggplot, with the use of data.frame, it seems it sorts out the data, but I want ot keep the data as is, so they can the same way in the plot.

Data are in this [link](https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv)

My code with help from some great coders on this community, the first part keep the data sorted the way I want:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(stringr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(matrixStats, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(pheatmap, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(heatmaps, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dfc <- read.csv(url("https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv"))

values <- c('S100a10', 'Esm1', 'Itgb1', 'Anxa2', 'Hist1h1b', 
                                                'Il2rb', 'Lgals1', 'Mki67', 'Rora', 'S100a4', 
                                                'S100a6', 'Adam8', 'Areg', 'Bcl2l1', 'Calca', 
                                                'Capg', 'Ccr2', 'Cd44', 'Csda', 'Ehd1', 
                                                'Id2', 'Il10', 'Il1rl1', 'Il2ra', 'Lmna', 
                                                'Maf', 'Penk', 'Podnl1', 'Tiam1', 'Vim',
                                                'Ern1', 'Furin', 'Ifng', 'Igfbp7', 'Il13', 
                                                'Il4', 'Il5', 'Nrp1', 'Ptprs', 'Rbpj', 
                                                'Spry1', 'Tnfsf11', 'Vdr', 'Xcl1', 'Bmpr2', 
                                                'Csf1', 'Dst', 'Foxp3', 'Itgav', 'Itgb8', 
                                                'Lamc1', 'Myo1e', 'Pmaip1', 'Prdm1', 'Ptpn5', 
                                                'Ramp1', 'Sdc4')

dfg <- dfc[match(rev(values), dfc$tracking_id), ]

dfg$CD44low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44low_rep1', 'CD44low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
rownameshm <-paste(dfg[,1])
colnameshm <- paste(dQuote(colnames(dfg[0, 10:13])), collapse = ", ")
dfg$Mean <- rowMeans(dfg[,10:13])
dfg$sd <- rowSds(as.matrix(dfg[,10:13]))

zScore <- function(p){
for(n in 10:13){
    p[[n]]=(as.numeric(p[[n]])-as.numeric(p[[14]]))/as.numeric(p[[15]])
    }
return(p)
}

Matrix_zScore <- t(apply(dfg,1,zScore))

Matrix_zScore_temp <- mapply(Matrix_zScore[,10:13], FUN=as.numeric)
Matrix_zScore_temp <- matrix(data=Matrix_zScore_temp, ncol=4, nrow=57)
Matrix_zScore_temp1<-as.data.frame(Matrix_zScore_temp)

rownames(Matrix_zScore_temp) <- dfg$tracking_id
plot_frame <- reshape2::melt(Matrix_zScore_temp)
```

This following (second) part of the code that causing the data to be sorted (which I don't want), I'm thinking the data.frame function in ggplot is causing the problem:

```
library("tidyverse", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(repr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
options(repr.plot.width=3, repr.plot.height=8)
tiff("test.tiff", units="in", width=3, height=8, res=300)

ggplot(plot_frame, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", position = position_dodge(), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = "", value = 0), size = 5,
             aes(color = factor(Var2))) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = " ", value = 1), alpha = 0) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "forestgreen", "red4", "blue4"),
                     labels = c("CD44 T Cells",
                                "CD44 CD69 T Cells",
                                "CD44 CD69 CD103-lo T Cells",
                                "CD44 CD69 CD103-hi T Cells"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA))) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  labs(y = "", fill = "") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#3C57A8", "white", "#DE2D29"),
                       breaks = c(1.5, 0, -1.5),
                        labels = c("1.0", "0", "-1.0"),
                        limits = c(-1.5, 1.5),
                       space = "Lab",
                       na.value = "grey50",
                       guide = "colourbar",
                       aesthetics = "fill") +
  theme_minimal() + 
theme (panel.grid.major = element_blank(), axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l = unit(-5, "cm")))) +
theme (axis.text.y = element_text(face="italic", size=7, color="black")) +
    guides(
        fill = guide_colourbar(
            title = "Relative gene expression \n (z score)",
            title.position = "right",
            title.theme = element_text(angle = -90, size = 7.5),
            direction = "vertical",
            ticks = TRUE
        )) +
theme(
    legend.justification = c(-0.9, 0), 
    legend.direction = "vertical",
    legend.key.size = unit(0.6, "cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(0.2,"cm"),
    legend.title.align = 0.5)

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty string specification in `Var1` in your `geom_point` functions is messing up the `ggplot2` behavior, since it's expecting a numeric value. Replace it by 0 and it should work as expected.

---

From:

```
...
geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = "", value = 0), size = 5,
           aes(color = factor(Var2))) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = " ", value = 1), alpha = 0) +
...
```

To:

```
...
geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = 0, value = 0), size = 5,
           aes(color = factor(Var2))) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(Var2 = 1:4, Var1 = 0, value = 1), alpha = 0) +
...
```

Comment: After you advise, which nicely worked, the color dots underneath the plot overlapped with the plot, any input how to fix it? @CainãMaxCouto-Silva